# Aligning indicator to screen, seperate from main price scale (similar to built in volume bars)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am making a sessions/killzone indicator and want to align the "session zones" all at the bottom of the screen.

The session zones only care about time and are independant of price or instrument etc.

[image]

As per the image, I want to get all boxes aligned at the bottom of the screen, in a similar way to how volume is aligned to the bottom.

I have tried setting a different scale on the inidcator, adding a different asset such as USD/USD, to plot against the 0.00 price... but nothing works.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1 - scale.left / scale.right**

I tried to replicate the volume indicator on its own scale, using scale.right/left. This does not seem to work. I tried with overlay = true and false.

[image]

**Edit 2**

I rebuilt the inidicator from scratch using scale.none and it now works. I think left/right would also work too but I must have had somethign else in the original code that stopped it working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indicator` call has a `scale` parameter you can use just for that:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true, scale = scale.right)
plot(volume, style = plot.style_histogram)
```

> scale (scale_type) The price scale used. Possible values: scale.right, scale.left, scale.none. The scale.none value can only be applied in combination with `overlay = true`. Optional. By default, the script uses the same scale as the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this but it still keeps it on the same scale as the instrument. Any ideas why this does not work? I added a screenshot to my iniitial question edit.

Comment: That's probably because the chart scale (not the indicator scale) is turned off. Go to the chart settings by hovering over the title where it says "GBPUSD 1D" and press the 3 dots. There you will see "pin to scale". Play around with one a few options you have there, and it should work fine. You will have 2 scales (one of the bar chart and one of the indicator) to adjust as you wish

Comment: I started a new indicator from scratch using scale.none, just applying RSI. This worked OK, so I then built the other parts of my indicator back into it. I guess there must have been something else in the original code that was stopping it from working as expected. Thank you!